# Reading URL Extension remiving [.] from it

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
return (url = url.substr(1 + url.lastIndexOf("/")).split('?')[0]).split('&')[0].substr(url.lastIndexOf("."));
```

I have above code which return [.exe] or [.pdf]

Where I expect only [EXE] or [PDF] 
What changes do I require in the above code?

Comment: You can simplify this with regular expressions `url.match(/[^.]+$/)[0]` this will work if you're sure that there is extension at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Just Add 1 to  last Index

```
 return (url = url.substr(1 + url.lastIndexOf("/")).split('?')[0]).split('&')[0].substr(url.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```